# Compile a set of functions to .LIB and .DLL at the same time

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

There is any preprocessor trick or something in which you can compile both, a lib and dll version, at the same time of a set of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain of the details on how to do this in Visual Studio, but basically you'll just have to set up two build products that build from the same source code, but with different build settings, such as a macro that enables/disables the `declspec()` attributes used in dlls.

I think in Visual Studio this might manifest as having two projects in your solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will do two projects then, over the same code, copy and modify one project to keep the folder organization structure inside the project

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't have to know whether you're making a static or dynamic library -- it just makes object files.

You can then take those object files and pass them to the library manager (creating a static library) or the linker (and create a shared object / DLL), and yes you can do both with the same object files, as long as you use a linker definition file to control DLL exports.

A convenient way to do with with Visual Studio is to set up a DLL project dependent on the static library, and select the ["Use Library Dependency Inputs"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VC.PROJECT.REFERENCES%29&rd=true) option for that dependency, in order to ensure that all global objects are included and not just those defined in the same compilation unit as an export.  Then the files will only be compiled once, but used to build two libraries.  (Of course, if you're running into issues with global objects, your static library is likely broken for other consumers anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, I take note about the dll project dependent on static library and will look more about :)

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, you need to create two independent projects sharing the same source files. And qualify the references you want to expose with a preprocessor symbol such as _DLL, substituted with empty for a static lib or with dll_export/dll_import when building or invoking the dynamic lib.

Comment: I just saw all replies at once, very fast all of you guys :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the library/DLL option is *per-configuration* and a single project may have multiple configurations, you can do this by adding (for example) `static-debug`, `dynamic-debug`, and so on. This is similar to how the CRT is handled, with static and dynamic, debug and not, and in the past threaded and not.

In order to do this, you'll need to use the configuration manager to add additional configurations for your projects, then you can do a batch build and select any combination of those you like.

You may want to use a text editor to copy the existing configurations and rename them, if you have many custom settings which are in the project/configuration itself (instead of global project or in a split properties file).

Comment: Thank you @peachykeen well explained :)

Answer (score 1):

Outputting static library or dynamic library does not depend on compiler. It is linker's job. Compiler generates .obj files which are linked by linker into (when conditions are met, such as you need entry point for .exe) what you want.

Specifically, MS linker `link.exe` has several output flags:

```
no flag: .exe is produced;
/LIB: static library .lib produced;
/DLL: dynamic library .dll and import library .lib produced;
```

In case of `/DLL` you also want to decorate your exported functions/classes with `__declspec(dllexport)`, so linker will put them in the import library. Also, note that static library and import library are NOT equivalent, even though they both have .lib extension. There are also additional files can be produced by the linker: here is [link to MSDN article on link.exe options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

EDIT: As Ben pointed out, `link.exe /LIB` really invokes `lib.exe` for static library. Running `link /LIB` yields (Windows SDK 7.1 SP1):

```
D:\Programs\Windows SDK 7.1>link /lib
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: LIB [options] [files]

   options:

      /DEF[:filename]
      /ERRORREPORT:{NONE|PROMPT|QUEUE|SEND}
      /EXPORT:symbol
      /EXTRACT:membername
      /INCLUDE:symbol
      /LIBPATH:dir
      /LIST[:filename]
      /LTCG
      /MACHINE:{ARM|EBC|IA64|MIPS|MIPS16|MIPSFPU|MIPSFPU16|
                SH4|THUMB|X64|X86}
      /NAME:filename
      /NODEFAULTLIB[:library]
      /NOLOGO
      /OUT:filename
      /REMOVE:membername
      /SUBSYSTEM:{BOOT_APPLICATION|CONSOLE|EFI_APPLICATION|
                  EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER|EFI_ROM|EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER|
                  NATIVE|POSIX|WINDOWS|WINDOWSCE}[,#[.##]]
      /VERBOSE
      /WX[:NO]
```

Comment: You don't need `__declspec(dllexport)` in source code to create a DLL, you can use a linker definition file.  Also static libraries and import libraries are different content in the same file format (and in fact you can have `.lib` files with both imports and object code)

Comment: There is no such `/LIB` option.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx) are the valid options.

Comment: @BenVoigt I meant, using `__declspec(dllexport)` so you get automatically generated import library. Sure, you can use `/EXPORTS` in .def as well. I just find `__declspec(dllexport/dllimport)` handy. And I'm not sure you can export classes with .def. Can you? Regarding static library and import library: can you have function in combined .lib both in static and dynamic form? How linker will tell which one to use? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @BenVoigt There is /LIB option. Otherwise, how can you specify static library to `link.exe`? In fact, I am using this option as we speak in my makefile.

Comment: Exporting classes is a bug, not a feature.  As for the hybrid .lib, I mean that some symbols will be imports, and other symbols (with different names) will be actual code.

Comment: You don't use `LINK.EXE` to create static libraries (they aren't linked at all), you use `LIB.EXE`, the library manager.

Comment: Well, you are correct about `lib.exe`: `/LIB` switch for `link.exe` invokes `lib.exe`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7765/discussion-between-azza-and-ben-voigt)